# FullCalendar: Default timezone irrespective of client's location

Tags: javascript, timezone, fullcalendar, timezone-offset

I am trying to create an appointment-scheduling application with `fullcalendar`. I want to represent time-slots on the calendar in only one timezone(i.e., EST) across all locations. So even if a person from PST zone is viewing the calendar, the times should be in EST. Also, even he/she schedules clicks a slot, the time should be in EST. How can I set a default time-zone for the calendar irrespective of location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be done by specifying the timezone string when you initialize your calendar:

```
$('#calendar-selector-id-name').fullCalendar({
    timezone: 'American/Indiana/Indianapolis'
});
```

You mentioned the `gcal.js` and so, I am wondering if this needs to be defined like:

```
$('#calendar-selector-id-name').fullCalendar({
    timezone: 'American/Indiana/Indianapolis',
    eventSources:[{
        url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/...',
        currentTimezone: 'American/Indiana/Indianapolis'
    }]
});
```

[Demo](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.0/demos/timezones.html)

[Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/)

[Timezone problems when using Google Calendar #1801](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1801)

**EDIT**

@jaykumarark did some further research and dug up the following:

[Google Calendar - htmlLink not always defined #2844](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2844)

Which revealed that for GoogleApps calendars, an initialized `htmlLink` variable is not provided for events that only share free/busy information, and hide event details.

Jay also noted discovering the following work-around:

"commenting line 144 in gcal.js `//url=injectQsComponent(url, 'ctz=' + timezoneArg);` I could represent times in a particular timezone irrespective of location."

So, in summary:

- Currently, setting timezone, irrelevant of location, seems to work
  fine with GoogleApps calendars, as long one of the 3 "Share all
  information, ..." sharing settings is selected.
- [Adam Shaw](https://github.com/arshaw) has acknowledged the issue of
  `htmlLink` requiring an existence check, i.e. at some point the
  javascript error will be addressed.
- Jay has provided a work-around, for those looking to implement 
  a synonymous solution.

Please refer to comments below for additional information/clarifications.

Comment: I get an error when i write: `timezone: 'American/Indiana/Indianapolis'`. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined (gcal.js: 174)`. All my time-slots disappear when this happens. I got the latest v.2.6 of the calendar. if I type `timezone: local` then no issue.

Comment: try the one that's just 'America/Indianapolis'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones ... actually, I totally forgot that FullCalendar switched to Moment.js for this stuff. These docs maybe pertinent to your solution as well: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I tried 'America/Indianapolis' and that didn't work. Also, both the wiki and moment.js docs use 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis'.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I am using `gcal.js` in my application to load events from google calendar. Is timezone not supported for this plugin?

Comment: good question on `gcal.js`. will have to research that one, myself. i think you are onto something though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101809/discussion-between-michael-stilson-and-jaykumarark).

Comment: It's more appropriate to use `America/New_York` to represent the US Eastern Time zone.  Indiana has a somewhat unique history. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson I agree with you. I prefer to use that one or `America/Detroit` for eastern timezone representations.

Comment: Was curious, did this answer your question @jaykumarark ?

Comment: @Michael Stilson, after looking around this is the issue https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2844 I'm facing. for events which do not share free/busy information(private data) google does not provide a `htmlLink`. If timezone is set, gcal uses the url provided(`htmlLink`) to construct get `url` with params. But since `htmlLink` is `undefined`, string operations fail.

Comment: @jaykumarark Ah, yes ... this totally makes sense. Good research there, buddy, and thanks for sharing the information. :)

Comment: @MichaelStilson after commenting line 144 in gcal.js (`//url=injectQsComponent(url, 'ctz=' + timezoneArg);`) I could represent times in a particular timezone irrespective of location. I think url attribute is used when user clicks on a slot and it shows a popup of the original appointment in google calendar. I have no use for that in my case. It works good now. Thanks for your efforts as well! :) Please add this to your answer. I will accept it. Without this post I wouldn't have been motivated to search.